# React-SpringBoot implementing URL shortener redirection

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn a few things by implementing a URL Shortner using Spring-boot, React, SQLite3.

My `Controller` class is supposed to

- render the `index` when someone goes to `http://localhost:8080`. Where they get the option to input a long URL, click a button, to get a shortened URL say `aBcD`. This is `index()` at path `/`.
- redirect to long URL when someone goes to `http://localhost:8080/aBcD`. This is `redirectTinyurl()` at path `/{shortUrl}`.
- I've also added the REST API that creates these mappings (long <> short) in same `Controller`. This is `createTinyurl()` at path `/tinyurl`.

Problem (I think) is when `index` is rendered, and browser tries to fetch `http://localhost:8080/main.css` it matches up with URL pattern (`/{shortUrl}`) and Spring calls `redirectTinyurl()` in teh `Controller`.

Is there a way to make Spring serve such resources by itself and also call my `redirectTinyurl()` when appropriate? Or a way where in I can pass some calls to Spring, if I can figure out that this is a request for resource not someone trying to resolve a URL.

Interestingly it can differentiate between `/tinyurl` and `/{shortUrl}`.

My `main.css` is already in `src/main/resources/static/main.css`.
[Here is full folder structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmjuD.png)

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private final TinyUrlRepository repository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        logger.info("rendering index");
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{shortUrl}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> redirectTinyurl(@PathVariable String shortUrl) {
        logger.info("redirectTinyurl() shortUrl: {}", shortUrl);
        UrlMapping resolvedUrl = repository.findById(Long.parseLong(shortUrl)).get();
        logger.info("redirecting to: resolvedUrl: {}", resolvedUrl);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(URI.create(resolvedUrl.getLongUrl()));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/tinyurl")
    @ResponseBody
    public String createTinyurl(@RequestBody UrlMappingPojo body /*contains long URL*/) {
          // ... create a mapping, store in DB and return a shortened URL
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>TinyURL experiment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="react"></div>
    <script src="built/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

```
2021-10-02 15:01:44.656  INFO 40980 --- rendering index
2021-10-02 15:01:44.985  INFO 40980 --- redirectTinyurl() shortUrl: main.css
2021-10-02 15:01:45.011 ERROR 40980 --- Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "main.css"] with root cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "main.css"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:707) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:832) ~[na:na]
    at com.greglturnquist.payroll.HomeController.redirectTinyurl(HomeController.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    .........
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code it seems like you are using Themeleaf in your project.

I replicated your problem with following,

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/{shortUrl}")
public ResponseEntity<String> redirectTinyurl(@PathVariable String shortUrl, HttpServletResponse response)  throws IOException {
    if(shortUrl.equals("google"))
        response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

This will redirect to google if someone goes to `http://localhost:8080/google`.

According to [WebMvcConfigurationSupport documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html), first it will consider the annotated controller methods. `/{shortUrl}` in your case. Since /main.css & `/{shortUrl}` has the similar url partern, both resolved to same method. However `/tinyirl` is specifically mentioned in the controller, it will not be confused with `/{shortUrl}`.

If you want to use the `main.css` and other in the same directory as your index, you will have to add wildcard patterns to exclude them using the controller method `/{shortUrl}`.

But there is a simple solution for solve this.(I think it is also a best practice) That is moving your main.css to folder similar to `/static/css/`.Refer the image below.

[image]

You can change the stylesheet reference as follows and you are good to go.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
```

What happened here is now. /css/main.css patern looks for a annotated controller method with `/{something}/{something}` . Since that is not there, it will go to resources and resolve the css file.

Comment: Thanks, but my main.css was already in `src/main/resources/static/main.css`. Added a link with picture of full folder structure. I updated to `href="/css/main.css"`. But same result.

Comment: I hope you also moved the main.css to css folder inside static folder. Are there any other configurations that you have defined for URL mapping?